# Making an impulse with a JavaScriptNode (Web Audio API)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm working with the Web Audio API, and I'm trying to make a JavaScriptNode that outputs an impulse.  That is, I want a node that will output a 1 followed by a whole bunch of zeros, and nothing else.

I thought the code below would be a sensible way to do this.  I initialize a variable called "timeForAnImpulse" to true and use this variable to trigger an impulsive output on the audio callback.  In the callback, I then set "timeForAnImpulse" to false.

This seems like it should work, but it doesn't.  Instead of a single impulse, I get an impulse train (a 1 at the start of each buffer). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = init;

    function impulseNodeCB(evt){

        if(timeForAnImpulse){
            var buf = evt.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            buf[0] = 1;
            timeForAnImpulse = false;
        }
    }

    var timeForAnImpulse = true;

    function init() {
        var context = new webkitAudioContext();
        impulseNode = context.createJavaScriptNode(2048,0,1);
        impulseNode.onaudioprocess = impulseNodeCB;
        impulseNode.connect(context.destination);   
    }

</script>

</head>
```

Comment: so are you just trying to create an extremely brief 'click'? interesting..

Comment: Exactly. Impulses come in handy when you're testing/debugging signal processing structures, though I admit they're not much fun to listen to. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out!

I had assumed that the output buffer `evt.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0)` was initialized with zeros at the start of each callback.  It isn't.  Instead, it seems to retain its values from its last invocation. Explicitly zeroing the buffer in an `else` clause solved the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = init;

    function impulseNodeCB(evt){

        if(timeForAnImpulse){
            var buf = evt.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
            buf[0] = 1;
            timeForAnImpulse = false;
        } else {
            buf[0] = 0;
        }
    }

    var timeForAnImpulse = true;

    function init() {
        var context = new webkitAudioContext();
        impulseNode = context.createJavaScriptNode(2048,0,1);
        impulseNode.onaudioprocess = impulseNodeCB;
        impulseNode.connect(context.destination);   
    }

</script>

</head>
```

Comment: You probably should set every value in buf every time, not just buf[0]. The API spec doesn't make any promises, so the output buffer could contain garbage. You could also get the same result more efficiently by using an AudioBufferSourceNode.